# How to make one object fit into volume of another?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, shape-keys

I need one object to mimic shape of another, so that it would fit it's volume and shape. Circle (2d) needs to be shaped like those crooked cube. As if you put something soft into some hard box, I need changed circle, cube is just for shaping  *(preferably for Blender 2.8, but not necessarily)*.
[image]

Comment: you don't give enough details about what your objects look like, but have you tried shapekeys?

Comment: @moonboots I updated question, no I didn't - don't know yet how to use them.

Comment: so maybe check shapekeys and see if it could answer, if your shapes are really basic I think it will easily do the trick

Comment: @moonboots I took a look at shapekeyes - it seems that's not what I need. I need circle automatically fit into the box.

Comment: why is it not what you need? with shapekeys you can transform a circle into another shape, like a square for example

Comment: do you have pictures of your objects? do they have details, materials? are they in 3D or are they flat (2D)?

Comment: @moonboots I mentioned circle (2d) and curved cube (3d).

Comment: ok but you don't give enough details, a circle can be morphed to a square, what do you mean when you want it to fit a cube? and why can't you do it with shapekeys which allow you to transform meshes? please provide more details

Comment: @moonboots I think it doesn't fit because I already have mesh shaped like I need , precisely (with necessary curvature). Imagine if you put something soft into some hard box. I need changed circle, cube is just for shaping.

Comment: if anyone else runs across this I think what your wanting is the Shrinkwrap Modifier

Answer (score 3):

How about:

- Make a box
- Make a circle which fits the box
- Make a Lattice object which fits the box
- Assign a Lattice modifier to the circle and the box

Now, whatever you do to the lattice, will happen to the circle and the box.

[image]

Or, if you have to fit to an existing box, make the Lattice to fit the circle, and then snap its vertices to the box.

Comment: Not quite automatic, but not bad at all, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a try with some shapekeys:

- Create your object, a circle if it begins with a circle.
- In the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Shape Keys*, create a basic shapekey, then a second one.
- Switch to *Edit* mode, select the second shapekey and edit your mesh, make it a bent square.
- Now back to *Object* mode, if you play with the shapekey *Value* you can morph from a shape to the other.

[image]

Comment: You said "make it a bent square" - how do I do that ? Manually ? That's exactly what should be avoided. And bent square is already there as a separate object. Good tutorial though, thanks.

Comment: why don't you want to make it one object? why avoid manually?

Comment: because it will take a lot of time to move all circle's vertexes into positions that I need and it's not gonna be that precise. I don't need shapekeys at all to shape it into something else, I could just do it.

Comment: it took me 2 minutes to do it and it can be as precise as you want so I'm not sure what you mean...